# Encryption in c lang. and decryption in c#

Tags: c#, c, encryption-symmetric

I have used Rijndael (Encryption Algorithm) in my server side code, which is in C language. But my client is written in C# and C# provide its own Rijndael class to encrypt and decrypt.

At client side I am using the same password for key generation but the client application is unable to decrypt it. I want to encrypt a file in C and decrypt that file in .NET (C#).

Server Code : http://www.efgh.com/software/rijndael.txt

Client Code :

```
    public static void Encrypt()
    {

        string password = @"4c696e6775614e6578742431302a4c6f63616c697a6174696f6e2a3949505f3030372a"; // Your Key Here
            /*UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
            byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);*/
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes  pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes (password, new byte[] { 0x26, 0xdc, 0xff, 0x00, 0xad, 0xed, 0x7a, 0xee, 0xc5, 0xfe, 0x07, 0xaf, 0x4d, 0x08, 0x22, 0x3c });

            string cryptFile = @"F:\Encoding and Decoding\ReadMe_Encrypted.txt";
            FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(cryptFile, FileMode.Create);

            RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();
            RMCrypto.KeySize = 256;
            RMCrypto.BlockSize = 256;               
            byte[] key = pdb.GetBytes(RMCrypto.KeySize / 8);
            byte[] iv = pdb.GetBytes(RMCrypto.BlockSize / 8);  
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,
                RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, iv),
                CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(@"F:\Encoding and Decoding\ReadMe.txt", FileMode.Open);

            int data;
            while ((data = fsIn.ReadByte()) != -1)
                cs.WriteByte((byte)data);

            fsIn.Close();
            cs.Close();
            fsCrypt.Close();

    }
    public static void Decrypt()
    {
        string password = @"4c696e6775614e6578742431302a4c6f63616c697a6174696f6e2a3949505f3030372a"; // Your Key Here

       /* UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
        byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);*/
       // PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, new byte[] { 0x26, 0xdc, 0xff, 0x00, 0xad, 0xed, 0x7a, 0xee, 0xc5, 0xfe, 0x07, 0xaf, 0x4d, 0x08, 0x22, 0x3c });
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, new byte[] { 0x26, 0xdc, 0xff, 0x00, 0xad, 0xed, 0x7a, 0xee, 0xc5, 0xfe, 0x07, 0xaf, 0x4d, 0x08, 0x22, 0x3c });

        FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(@"F:\Encoding and Decoding\ReadMe_Encrypted.txt", FileMode.Open);

        RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();
        RMCrypto.KeySize = 256;
        RMCrypto.BlockSize = 256;
        byte[] key = pdb.GetBytes(RMCrypto.KeySize / 8);
        byte[] iv = pdb.GetBytes(RMCrypto.BlockSize /8);  
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, RMCrypto.CreateDecryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
     //   CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, RMCrypto.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);


        FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(@"F:\Encoding and Decoding\ReadMe_Decrypted.txt", FileMode.Create);

        int data;
        while ((data = cs.ReadByte()) != -1)
            fsOut.WriteByte((byte)data);

        fsOut.Close();
        cs.Close();
        fsCrypt.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. First off, you should give some relevant code details and describe what you've tried and how you've failed. Secondly, "please reply" may be considered as rude and attention-seeking by some. StackOverflow is a site for the *community* first and for yourself second only: If your question is well-researched and interesting, people will answer it, and if not they won't.

Comment: It is not about language you use, it is about algorithm and its implementation.

Comment: @RenéKolařík The language is quite relevant, since many of these kind of algorithms are written in C using bit-wise operators, that may not be available in other languages.

Comment: I can do same thing with Obj-C and C#. so, must accomplishable to you. just provide both side of code that you use, i am sure someone here will figure out for you.

Comment: I want to know is there any way or algo which supports both languages

Comment: @Lundin C# has these operators and in any language you can just simulate them.

Comment: @RenéKolařík That's easier said than done depending on your background. An example from the real word: a friend of mine is a Delphi/desktop guru with some 30+ years of programming experience. He needed to convert an encryption algorithm from C to Object Pascal and came to me for help with C interpretation. I found out that things I regard as basic and fundamental:  bit shifts, bit masking, hex literals etc, were completely unknown to him, since he never had a need for them before. So instead of translating, he decided to compile and link the C code as a DLL which he imported to Delphi.

Answer (score 2):

In your C# code you're using `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` to convert your password string into a 256-bit key (under the hood this is actually hashing the password using SHA-1), whereas in the C code you're using the key directly. You probably want to modify the C# code to use the key directly (it looks like a 256-bit key to me, not an ASCII password).

The following should be sufficient:

```
byte[] key = {0x4c, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x67, ...};
```

You'll also want to modify the C program to use the correct binary key, rather than taking one on the command line. You can use something like the following:

```
unsigned char key[KEYLENGTH(KEYBITS)] = {0x4c, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x67, ...};
```

I'm also not sure if you're using the same mode (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation). I think the C# code may be using CBC whereas the C code is using ECB. I suggest this as there's an iv in the C# code (generated from the password), but there isn't one in the C code.

You could also try to find a library that you can use from both C and C# and use that instead, for example openssl.

Comment: hi jleahy..i have used same hexadecimal string as a password at both side..so password is same @ both side...But i think they(client & server) generate different keys by using same password

Comment: That's because you're using different techniques to generate the key from the password, as I mentioned. If you can make this bit identical it should work. I'm also not certain you're using the same mode, answer amended above.

Comment: problem is not solved yet...if anybody knows the answer please help